# CSS Margin Issue

Tags: css

i have an issue with my css where if i use `margin: 0` instead of `margin-top: 0`, for `header p`, the `header { margin: 0 0 20px; }` will be as good as not there. isit supposed to be like that? if i see what happens in firebug, its because the `margin-bottom` of `header` *collapsed* into the next sibling, the `section`.

[image]

html

```
<header>
    <h1>ToDo List</h1>
    <p>HTML5 Offline Capable Web Application</p>
</header>
```

css

```
header { font: 24px/1em Notethis; color: #666; margin: 0 0 20px; }
header h1 { font: 60px/1.4em Hetilica; margin: 0; }
header p { margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: Excellently asked question. Bravo.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is this question 'off-topic'? (I ask because I'm curious as to the reason for the close-vote). Admittedly it's css rather than programming, but it's hardly unique in that, and the community seems to be broadly okay with that, judging by the number of css questions here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem here is that your `header` element is not actually rendering any `margin` applied to it at all. The space you are seeing is actually the result of a default `margin` applied to  `header p`.

The reason I say this is that many browsers will not automatically treat the `header` tag as a block-level element unless explicitly defined as such:

```
header { display: block; }
```

After applying this statement to `header` in your CSS I could successfully apply `header p { margin: 0 }` and retain the margin specified in `header` itself. Removing this statement will revert back to the behaviour you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Firebug only show you part of the story.

To see what really happens when you change `margin-top: 0;` for `margin: 0 0 0 0;`, please click on the arrow right to the Style tab (above '`header p`' on your snapshot) and select "Display default CSS properties" or sth like that and you'll see downward that html.css already styles p as:

```
p {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Beware, do NOT modify system styles or you'll have to restart Firefox, reopening tabs won't be sufficient.

BTW this `1em` margin is what you see in HTML without any style (menu Display / Page style / No style in Firefox or CSS menu of *Web Developer Toolbar*) : your paragraphs have some vertical margin.

So basically you erased a `1em` bottom margin.

Comment: oh thanks! but the qn will then be why didn't the `header { margin: 0 0 20px; }` do anything? oh @matt answered this qn... 

"many browsers will not automatically treat the `header` tag as a block-level element unless explicitly defined "